# R connection to sqlite

Tags: r, sqlite

I am unable to connect to sqlite from R.  Sqlite3 is installed on the linux server and am able to create/modify. But R isn't connecting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

> db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = TRUE)
Error in .local(drv, ...) : Could not connect to database:
unable to open database file
```

I am able to connect to SQLite from the command line:

```
@ubuntu:~$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Here is the session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_1.0.0 DBI_0.3.1     dplyr_0.4.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.1       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.2.2 tools_3.2.2   
[6] Rcpp_0.12.1   
>
```

Answer (score 6):

SQLite is a file level database, hence to reference it requires a full directory path. No where do you specify the working directory or a full path in the file name.

By default, R will use the current working directory contained in `getwd()`. If database is not contained in this folder, then connection error will emerge. You can change working directory with `setwd()`.

By the way, you reference both packages but are connecting to SQLite with the `dplyr` package using [src_sqlite](http://www.inside-r.org/node/230652), not with RSQLite.

**RSQLite Connection**

```
library(RSQLite)

setwd("/Path/To/Database/Folder")
sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
conn <- dbConnect(sqlite,"my_db.sqlite3")
```

**DPLYR Connection**

```
library(dplyr)

setwd("/Path/To/Database/Folder")
db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = TRUE)
```

You might not want to call both libraries together to avoid conflict of same named functions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and responding.  I am using the dplyr connection. although I didn't specifically set setwd(), am ok with the R picking the default path.  I am experiencing this on Linux, on OS-X, I don't see this issue.  I also hardwired the path with setwd(), just to make sure setting the path is not the issue, with the same result.                                                                                                        db1 <- src_sqlite("db1.sqlite3", create = T)
Error in .local(drv, ...) : Could not connect to database:
unable to open database file

Comment: In Linux, you have to grant [read/write access](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/760276-how-to-manage-file-and-folder-permissions-in-linux) to individual files and folders. Be sure to do so prior to R connection.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [RSQLite's vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html):

> RSQLite is a DBI-compatible interface which means you primarily use functions defined in the DBI package, so you should always start by loading DBI, not RSQLite:

```
library(DBI)
```

After loading DBI in your environment, you can connect to an existing database or create a new one:

```
dbh <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "mydb.sqlite")
dbDisconnect(dbh)
#> [1] TRUE
unlink("mydb.sqlite")
```

You will find more examples in the above link to RSQLite's vignette. I have also some examples in [my blog](http://scbits.blogspot.com/2016/11/using-sqlite-with-r.html). I hope this helps! :)