# Connect to SQLite db without changing wd

Tags: r, path, rsqlite

Is there a way to specify a connection path to an SQLite database from R without re-setting my wd?

I've looked through the `DBI::dbConnect()` and `RSQLite::SQLite()` documentation, but it is still not clear to me how (or if) this can be accomplished. So far, the only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545777/r-connection-to-sqlite/32546468#32546468) I've come across is to `setwd()`, but this is something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Instead I'd rather include a path, something like...

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

path_db <- "E:/"

# ... this still looks in my current wd... how to I get it to look on the E-drive?
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "dummy_data.db")
```

... but I can't figure out how I should get the path in there... most of the tutorials {[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html), [2](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-in-r)} I've come across seem to assume the database is in the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the path in the db name:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

path_db <- "E:"

con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), file.path(path_db,'test.db'))
```

make sure that you have write access to E: to avoid :

```
Error : Could not connect to database:
unable to open database file
```

Comment: Wow -- can't believe I missed that. The advice on the write access is also appreciated!